# $h$ is a homomorphism, $f$ is any map and $a \neq b$. Then $h(f(a)) \neq h(f(b)) \implies f(a) \neq f(b)$

Tags: functions, modules, proof-explanation

Let $h$ is a homomorphism, $f$ is any map and $a \neq b$. Then $h(f(a)) \neq h(f(b)) \implies f(a) \neq f(b)$. This was a step in a proof when I was reading Free modules (to prepare for the so called universal mapping theory). In the setting, $f$ is a map between a set $S$ and R-module $F$ from Sze-Tsien Hu's book.

Comment: That is just a property of functions, if f(a) and f(b) we’re equal then the images under h would have to be equal

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: There is no question mark in your "question". Moreover, your last sentence is missing a period at the end. I'll fix that with an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, $g(a) \neq g(b) \implies a \neq b$.

Comment: So what if $g(x) = 1$?

Comment: Then $g(a) \neq g(b) \implies a \neq b$. This is vacuously true.

Comment: Nvm this is the contrapostive of the statement.

Comment: Yes, it is the contrapositive of $a=b \implies g(a) = g(b)$.

Comment: Yeah my brain must've just farted.

Answer (score 1):

The contrapositive is plainly true:

> $f(a) = f(b) \implies h(f(a)) = h(f(b))$